# setting proxy related information in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any way to set the network proxy and credentials in spring boot configuration?

Please help me out.

I'm using RestTemplate to call the rest api.

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687670/using-resttemplate-how-to-send-the-request-to-a-proxy-first-so-i-can-use-my-jun ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable proxy using below code snippets

```
 SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new   SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host,portNr);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,address);
    factory.setProxy(proxy);

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

Comment: Is there any possibly to configure in application.properties files.

Comment: @Goutham Yes possible using PropertySource annotaion and Value annotation. See examplehttp://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/