# how to avoid proxy while using rest template over proxy server

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

How to get the response from API using rest template over proxy network without setting proxy details?

Example: http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random.
I am getting response if opening the browsers, I am trying to consume the API through proxy network but I don't want to use proxyHost and proxyPort in code, getting error : **Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect**

public class RestWithoutProxy {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
    String url="http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
    System.out.println("... calling api");
    try{
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
                .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        System.out.println("response: "+ response.getBody());
    }catch(HttpStatusCodeException ex){
        int statusCode = ex.getStatusCode().value();
        System.out.println("error code: "+statusCode+"\n"+ex.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("......inside rest exception\n"+ ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Code is not working if using office network where proxy and firewall is enabled, but same code is working if using open network

Comment: The browser is probably getting the proxy settings from your machine. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376101/setting-jvm-jre-to-use-windows-proxy-automatically

Comment: Welcome to SO.
I've your network configuration requires a proxy, then you can't ignore it. Please show us your code

Comment: Make proxy settings optionally configurable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using RestTemplate, how to send the request to a proxy first so I can use my junits with JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687670/using-resttemplate-how-to-send-the-request-to-a-proxy-first-so-i-can-use-my-jun)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and after two day of debug, finally found the solution. Thought it's better to share this info even though this question was asked few months back.

**CAUSE:** 
If you are getting  Connection timed out exception then more likely you have proxy issue. 
**SOLUTION:**
In this case, we have to create `RestTemplate` using `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`.

You need to get the `Proxyhost` and proxy port from your server where you have hosted your application. 
for example - In tomcat, these details can be fetch using below snippet  -

```
System.getProperty("http.yourproxyHost.com")
System.getProperty("http.proxyPort")
```

Then you can use below Snippet:

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpReq = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("ur.proxy.com", port));
clientHttpReq.setProxy(proxy);
```

Now `RestTemplate` can be created in below way -

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpReq);
```

After this you can use your code. It will surely work. Let me know if you face any issue.