# Test communication of App through HTTP/S proxy

Tags: java, spring, rest, proxy, resttemplate

I am developing a REST application for a corporate environment where all POST/GET requests to an external system must go through a HTTPS-Proxy.

This is how I tell my app to go through the proxy:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564999/2069922

I need to develop this app outside of the corporate network, and would like to test communicating through the proxy. Is there an easy way to setup such a proxy locally? Or even better is there any public proxy I could use for testing?

Answer (score 0):

This python forward-proxy seems to work fine: https://github.com/allfro/pymiproxy