# Add Proxies dynamically to RestTemplate Bean

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a `RestTemplate` which I'd like to create as a Bean for ease of testing etc. This RestTemplate may or may not require the use of Proxies added to it. Currently I'm instantiating a new RestTemplate each request, and deciding whether to add the proxies based on a boolean flag, like this:

```java
private CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient(HttpProxy proxy, boolean proxyRequired){
  RequestConfig.Builder requestConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout();

  if(proxyRequired){
    requestConfigBuilder.setProxy(proxy); 
  }

  return HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfigBuilder.build()); 
}
```

And then my main method to construct the `RestTemplate`

```java
private RestTemplate createRestTemplate(List<String> httpProxyList,boolean proxyRequired) {
        final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = getHttpClient(httpProxyList,proxyRequired);
        final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpclient);
        final ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
```

Is there a way to do this where I can use the same RestTemplate bean each time, but dynamically add proxies to it as/when required?

Comment: Based on protocol with [ProxySelector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html). Based on target host with [RoutePlanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687670/using-resttemplate-how-to-send-the-request-to-a-proxy-first-so-i-can-use-my-jun?rq=4)

Comment: `setProxy()` should be attached when the http client is being created or customized.